# Как адаптировать ширину и высоту флексбокса под содержимое

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Задача:** максимально растянуть картинку, под которой расположены кнопки, при этом не должно оставаться пустых областей в родительских блоках (подразумевается что это модальное окно которое закрывается при клике по пустой области (синий блок на картинке - флексбокс должен обтекать картинку и кнопки)). Картинка не должна быть искажена или обрезана, может быть любых размеров, в зависимости от ориентации должна быть максимальна по высоте или ширине.

Единственная проблема которая осталась это выровнять флексбокс по ширине (синяя рамка должна обтекать картинку как на второй схеме).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block {
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block__Image {
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block__ButtonsWrapper {
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="Modal">
      <div tabindex="0">
        <!-- менять можно только здесь -->
        <div class="Block">
          <img class="Block__Image" src="https://get.pxhere.com/photo/tree-branch-plant-sunlight-leaf-flower-green-botany-maple-leaf-translucent-vegetation-deciduous-poplar-outbreak-flowering-plant-grape-leaves-plant-stem-woody-plant-land-plant-609015.jpg" />
          <div class="Block__ButtonsWrapper">
            <button>test</button>
            <button>test</button>
            <button>test</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Задача: максимально растянуть картинку .Block__Image{width:100%} так?

Comment: @LevShportak задача максимально растянуть по ширине и высоте сохранив пропорции, заранее не известно что больше

Answer (score 2):

#### Вариант 1 - максимальное растягивание изображения

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block {
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block__Image {
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;         /* ◄◄◄ */
  object-fit: cover;   /* ◄◄◄ */
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block__ButtonsWrapper {
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="Modal">
      <div tabindex="0">
        <!-- менять можно только здесь -->
        <div class="Block">
          <img class="Block__Image" src="https://get.pxhere.com/photo/tree-branch-plant-sunlight-leaf-flower-green-botany-maple-leaf-translucent-vegetation-deciduous-poplar-outbreak-flowering-plant-grape-leaves-plant-stem-woody-plant-land-plant-609015.jpg" />
          <div class="Block__ButtonsWrapper">
            <button>test</button>
            <button>test</button>
            <button>test</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

При маленьком изображении, оно не будет растягиваться - потому что не растягивается родительский элемент `<div tabindex="0">`.

---

#### Вариант 2 - подстройка размеров флексбокса

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block {
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block__Image {
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: calc(90vh - 27px - 6px);  /* ◄◄◄ */
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: calc(90vw - 6px);          /* ◄◄◄ */
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Block__ButtonsWrapper {
  /* test */
  border: 3px solid orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="Modal">
      <div tabindex="0">
        <!-- менять можно только здесь -->
        <div class="Block">
          <img class="Block__Image" src="https://get.pxhere.com/photo/tree-branch-plant-sunlight-leaf-flower-green-botany-maple-leaf-translucent-vegetation-deciduous-poplar-outbreak-flowering-plant-grape-leaves-plant-stem-woody-plant-land-plant-609015.jpg" />
          <div class="Block__ButtonsWrapper">
            <button>test</button>
            <button>test</button>
            <button>test</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

По сути недореспонсив, т.к. вычисляемые ограничения размеров компенсируют бордеры и высоту соседнего элемента - иначе никак не получится без изменения стилей родительского элемента (между зеленобордерным и синебордерным).

Comment: CSS-свойство `object-fit` не поддерживается IE (землю - крестьянам, фабрики - рабочим, [полифиллы](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fit-images) - некрофилам!).

Comment: Нужно чтобы изображение было полностью видно, с ```object-fit``` так же остается пустое пространство

Comment: @noctual, чтобы изображение было полностью видно - просто замени `object-fit: cover;` на `height: 100%;`, и наслаждайся чудесным искажением. А пустых пространств со значением `cover` не может оставаться (см. css-справочник, или значение этого англ. слова), если только эти пустоты не являются частью самогó изображения.

Comment: в том то и дело, изображение не должно быть искажено или обрезано. Уточнил вопрос.

Comment: @noctual, мы с геометрией не понимаем таких сферических коней которые в любых пропорциях не искажаются и не обрезаются... Просто покажи желаемый результат изображением (сделав его в графическом редакторе в двух вариантах: в альбомной ориентации, и в ландшафтной) - а я покажу как сделать его стилями.

Comment: добавил картинку в вопрос

Comment: @noctual, белые прямоугольники с надписями, без изображения и кнопок - это желаемый результат, именно так должна выглядеть верстка?

Comment: желаемый результат убрать пустое пространство в флексбоксе, в данном случае поскольку изображение вертикальное и уперлось в ограничение по высоте, нужно не изображение растягивать а сжать флексбокс. Когда изображение горизонтальное и упирается в ограничение по ширине мой код работает нормально. Сомневаюсь что вставив картинку вместо прямоугольников станет намного понятнее, но если нужно сейчас сделаю.

Comment: @noctual сжатие флексбокса делается удалением всяких `[min-|max-]width` и добавлением `flex-shrink: 1;` - это разрешит сокращение по основной оси (по ширине, в данном случае). А по высоте он уже сжимается (благодаря центральному выравниванию родителя по кросс-оси его родителя).

Comment: в данном случае основная ось вертикальная (```flex-direction: column;```), а вот по кросс-оси как раз таки и не сжимается

Comment: @noctual, в примере - сжимается. Для проверки, через devtools удали атрибут `src` у элемента `<img>` чтобы он схлопнулся, и увидишь что флексбокс сожмется до 39px == высоты кнопок и бордеров. И по ширине тоже исправно сжимается по кнопкам (удаление кнопок сожмет до бордеров), уж не знаю где ты видишь проблему... здесь она фактически отсутствует.

Comment: ```flex-shrink: 1;``` не работает т.к. не задана ширина

Comment: @noctual, повторяю: **в примере работает, проблема не воспроизводится**. Единица это значение по-умолчанию у `flex-shrink`, т.е. вообще оно работает "искаропки", а указывать его явно нужно только для надежности - на случай перекрытия этого свойства другим правилом с более общим селектором (ну и еще чтобы видеть в инспекторе, применяется ли свойство, если суеверия мучают: когда стиль отображается не перечеркнутым и без значков ошибки - это значит что он применяется, работает. Дополнительно убедиться можно через Computed styles).

Comment: возможно у меня проблемы со зрением или браузером, но я четко вижу большую пустую область между красной(img) и синей рамкой(flexbox) https://d.radikal.ru/d04/2108/f3/8320623d4583.png

Comment: @noctual, это пример не из моего ответа, очевидно же что стили другие... С твоими стилями и условием "менять можно только здесь" - невозможно реализовать респонсивное сжатие элемента с синим бордером (без явного указания ширины), потому что его родительский элемент с блочной моделью отображения, у которой по-умолчанию `width: 100%;`. Только если родителю "синего бордера" добавить стиль предполагающий сокращение по контенту (и синему бордеру добавить `min-width`) все начнет сжиматься. По-другому вроде никак.

Comment: @noctual, посмотри ответ, я там костылей свежих завез. Это максимум что можно сделать не трогая родителя, т.к. еще один оставшийся возможный вариант (о котором я думал изначально) оказалось напрочь блокирует авторесайз изображения, зажимая его под ширину строки кнопок (т.к. у безбордерного родителя автовысота), и в этом нет практического смысла.